# Executing functions (calculations) on mysql select query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a summary query where all result of the calculation are showed. I store only the data and on every request a function calculates the result. My problems is this method causes waiting times. I would like to reduce it. The best thing I could do is to cache the results for 24 hours.

I can not store the results, because many of the variables has to be changed easily.

What would be the best practice to run php functions on mysql select query?

Comment: Why don't you store result with data and pull it out when needed?

Comment: what about using stored procedures? since mysql 5.

Comment: @Tpojka What do you mean by storing with data?
Vickel: I have try that, but my calculations are very complex and Im not familiar with stored procedures on that high level. Also, its much easier and better to have the function in php, so its ready to be called.

Comment: of course it is easier with php! but you better invest to learn doing sql queries (and stored procedures) as it speeds up your queries in light-ages.